# Batch Normalization in the tf.layers module

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I am using the Tensorflow 1.0 tf.layers module. However, i am finding trouble understanding where to apply batch normalisation in the tf.layers.conv2d function.

If i am understanding well, this function has kernel and bias regularizers for L2/L1, and an activity regularizer. However, i an assumption is that the activity regularizer is applied after the activation function and not before. Hence, it could be used for dropout. I cannot understand where the batch normalization is applied. My thoughts are:

1. Is it default and always used?
2. Should i apply activation function as None and then pass the result through a batch norm layer and then a separate activation?

The second option will work. However, i have a feeling that a more elegant answer is available.